# How to establish the communication between the two Different EXEs

Tags: c#, windows, communication, exe

1.If A is a one windows forms application.
2.B is a another Windows forms application.
3. Have to Establish the connection between this applications how is it possible?

*EXAMPLE:*

IF I click the one button in the first program ,the click event have to be occur in the second program, and the result going to be reflect to the first program.

If I Click the second program the click event will be occur into the first program and result going to be reflect in the second program

So How to establish this two programs communication using the C# windows Application if any one Know the Answer please help me.it's very important for me.

Comment: Please let us know what you really want to accomplish, because there's no point in having two applications for that example case. When we know what you really want to do, we can better help you. There are verious ways for two processes to communicate, and which one is better depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Following are some of the possible options.

1) communicate using WCF based inter process communication

2) communicate via simple file based approach(one exe writes and other monitors and read)

3) communicate via sockets

4) communicate via Windows Message Queues

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Named Pipes and WCF.

If you perform a search on Google [named pipes wcf](http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&pq=wcf%20named%20pipes&xhr=t&q=named+pipes+wcf&cp=13&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=named+pipes+W&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b1a03ddafcac791b&biw=1680&bih=946) you should see enough information to get you started.

At a quick glance, I would say that this tutorial is a good starting point: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication